# Cannot start mysql anymore after fsck because of Apparmor permission and winbindd

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04, apparmor

We are on Ubuntu 20.04 and had several restarts and ran fsck. Now mysqld refuses to start:

```
Jan 16 12:40:01 example audit[1427]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/samba/winbindd/pipe" pid=1427 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 16 12:40:01 example kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1705405201.256:19): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/samba/winbindd/pipe" pid=1427 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

But what does winbindd have to do with Mysql?

My first guess was, that the winbindd/pipe file might share an inode with a file in /var/lib/mysql, but that does not seem the case:

```
root@example /var/lib/mysql # stat /run/samba/winbindd/pipe
  File: /run/samba/winbindd/pipe
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 19h/25d Inode: 696         Links: 1
Access: (0777/srwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2024-01-16 12:21:51.453451032 +0100
Modify: 2024-01-16 12:21:51.368164631 +0100
Change: 2024-01-16 12:21:51.368164631 +0100
 Birth: -
root@example /var/lib/mysql # find . -inum 696
root@example /var/lib/mysql # cd ..
root@example /var/lib # find . -inum 696
```

We did not change any apparmor configuration.

EDIT: If we disable the apparmor profile for mysqld, we still get

```
Jan 16 12:47:25 example systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

Comment: We decided to restore the full system from a backup, still it might be an interesting case to leave this question open.